# SQL MariaDB Events Navicat turn on

Tags: php, mysql, sql, windows, navicat

I can't turn on events in MariaDB (sql) in the program Navicat. This is the error I got:

[image]

How can I resolve this issue?

This is the query I try to run:

```
update user_stats set DailypetRespectPoints = 5
```

Comment: i think u need to add your query here

Comment: @devpro update user_stats set DailypetRespectPoints = 5

Comment: Please add complete of query to your questions.

Comment: Please go to SQL Previews tab and add the query you see here.